# Will the method in a fast enumeration definition only be called once or per iteration (objective-c)?

Tags: ios, objective-c, enumeration

Example

```
for(id obj in [self getObjectsSorted]) {
   ...
}
```

Will [self getObjectsSorted] be called once or per iteration?

Comment: If I liked guessing then I wouldn't have to post this question... I could just guess and make my own opinion then.. true facts is much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fast enumeration converts your counter and object into a immutable constant. And `start` and `end` of loop-counters are fixed at once. You can not change them.

Answer (score 0):

By checking with breakpoint it seems it is only called once.